# Command Line Web Apps

Tags: sockets, web-applications, command-line, command-line-interface

I've been looking into writing command line tools that interact with a web app recently, e.g a command line tool that orders a Jimmy  Johns sandwich.
I can think of 2 approaches to this:

- Socket programming and direct http input/output
- Opening up chrome invisibly and running JS scripts on it

What are the advantages / disadvantages of each method? Which one would you recommend? Are there any other (possibly better) methods to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Advantages/Disadvantages:

- Socket programming: lean but manual.
- Chrome: not lean but can use JS.

If the interface is RESTful, there are plenty of light-weight clients that give you both leanness and high-level operation.

[This](http://isbullsh.it/2012/06/Rest-api-in-python/) article covers communicating with RESTful APIs using python and concludes by recommending the tool "requests".

Answer (score 0):

The WebSocket protocol provides a way of creating web applications that support real-time bi-directional communication between clients and servers. Part of HTML5, WebSocket makes it much easier to develop these types of applications than the methods previously available. Most modern browsers support WebSocket including Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari, and Opera, and more and more server application frameworks are now supporting WebSocket as well.

There is some benefits if you use the websocket with https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

Hope this would help.